# i915 - Intel BayTrail - graphics artifacts

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, intel-graphics, graphic-card, i915

I just noticed I have some kind of graphics artifacts which effect visual discomfort like so called "blurry"; *And, moreover, I am not sure I have correct DPI settings right now (give me advise concerning DPI too pls)...*
I detected artifacts by taking screen by my mobile phone 60hz cam (see image)

[image]

...so, as I can get it, I need some graphics acceleration or i915 module fix or...?

**EDIT :** 
I have uxa acceleration mode right now cause visually it seems more clear ... the /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf content is :

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Intel Graphics" #or card0
    Driver "Intel"
    Option "AccelMethod" "uxa" #sna or uxa  
    Option      "Backlight"    "intel_backlight"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0" 
EndSection
```

**EDIT :** 
I just tried to install linux-mainline-baytrail 4.0rc4-1 and that's what I have in output :

```
linux-mainline-baytrail 4.0rc4-1  (Tue Mar 17 20:33:28 CDT 2015)
( Unsupported package: Potentially dangerous ! )
==> WARNING: This PKGBUILD describes a splitted package.
==> Specific package options are unknown
==> linux-mainline-baytrail dependencies:
 - docbook-xsl (already installed)
 - kmod (already installed)
 - inetutils (already installed)
 - bc (already installed)
 - xmlto (package found)
```

seems like kernel-3.16.7 already has something related to bay trail support or I don't know?

---

So my question is... how to analyse what causes the blurry effect, how to check if dpi is correct and how to fix the graphics artifacts?

Thanks

p.s.

- kernel-3.16.7
- os: linux arch x64
- video card : Intel HD Graphics (Bay Trail)

Comment: You said, you have Arch? Did you put i915 into MODULES in /etc/mkinitcpio.conf? Like it says [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics#Enable_early_KMS)

Comment: The lsmod outputs I have i915 module init-ed

Comment: But I don't have intel_agp module in lsmod list; Does it required or not?

Comment: and I am not sure what the instruction says "If you are using a custom EDID file, you should embed it into initramfs as well: " ?

Comment: How to get EDID file ? I tried read-edid util but get-edid outputs nothing :(

Comment: I found [this](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/linux-mainline-baytrail/) in AUR...hope it helps :) you could also try to compile the latest kernel and modules from source, since Bay Trail is relatively new, it might not yet be supported...sorry I can't help you more

Comment: @Alko I don't get it... You mean the BayTrail requires the whole another kernel or an additional module integration into the running one?

Comment: ...and what means the whole package name as "kernel26-mainline-baytrail=4.0rc4 " the 4.0rc4 means not final and equals to standard kernel v4.0 or ?... please give me a tip

Comment: Probably some modifications and modules, that are not yet in the main kernel branch...I can't say for sure..I don't even know what BayTrail is :P but checking online, there are others not even able to boot Linux in it. So I guess you're in luck https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/2cv73i/intel_hd_graphics_bay_trail_unsupported/

Comment: Have you read the hole Arch wiki page about Intel Graphics? At the bottom there are some fixes, other people have as well...check "Tear-free video" section, this might help.

Comment: @Alko "I don't even know what BayTrail is" The "BayTrail" is the type of intel microprocessor which has so called "Sandy Bridge" and build-in graphics, as I can remember :) Anyways, are you sure the problem I describe is related to "tear free video" thread?

Comment: I don't know...but you can try. What do you have to lose? :)

Comment: I need to find out a really helpful techniques combination to solve the issue I face right now; BTW previously I has SNA accel mode but it was really blurry, as I can remember it, so I replaced it with UXA which seems a quite better but UXA does not support 3D acceleration; So how you think will back to SNA + intel_apg handle the artifacts?

Comment: @Alko I just tried to install linux-mainline-baytrail 4.0rc4-1 but seems like it has duplicated packages or something? I edited my question text

Comment: Check the [PKGBUILD](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PKGBUILD) maybe there are some outdated packages inside or something...hope it helps

Comment: @Alko The PKGBUILD points kernel 4.x to be downloaded; I am not sure but seems like baytrail support starts from kernel 4.x; But what about intel hd graphics how to find out how kernel-4.0 for example supports really intel hd graphics?

Comment: I don't get it how to use menuconfig to set baytrail support in kernel-4.1? I couldn't find the option :( Please give me a tip

Comment: [This](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/sound/soc/intel/Kconfig) maybe? Strangely its for sound...

Comment: No, I mean I can see the driver in folders drivers/pinctrl/intel/ but how to enable it with menuconfig cause there may be dependencies %)

Comment: You can check the source, under which DEFINE is the BayTrail you need to enable. Then check which menu option enables it...depending on the version of menuconfig (I think) there is also a search option within.

Comment: @Alko "...under which DEFINE is the BayTrail you need to enable..." I am not sure; please give more details

Comment: I'm not sure either...you'll have to figure that out by yourself :)